# hide cursor from editText when soft keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is my first application and I am try to find a way to remove the cursor from edit box when I push the back button and the software keyboard disappeared. I tried to check if the back button pressed but this works only if you push the back button two times if the keyboard is on.

Below is a sample of my code with an editText and with back button check:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnGlobalLayoutListener
{
    boolean flag;
    double vc, vs, t, r, c;
    EditText resistor_E_T;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    resistor_E_T.setCursorVisible( false );
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    resistor_E_T = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.resistor_Edit_Text );
    resistor_E_T.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher( )
    {
        public void afterTextChanged( Editable s ) 
        {
            resistor_E_T.setCursorVisible( true );
            if ( Exceptions.isDouble( resistor_E_T.getText( ).toString( ) ) )
            {
                r = Double.parseDouble( resistor_E_T.getText( ).toString( ) );
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) { }

        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count ) { }
   });
```

Also, I found miscellaneous codes on the internet and in the stackoverflow that check if the keyboard is up via pixels but I couldn't make any code to work. Does anyone have an idea how can I do this or it is impossible.

**What happens now:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6alGK.png

**When the soft keyboard disappeared cursor still blinking:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpbkl.png

Comment: ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

use this one:-

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or you can use this in your xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

please let me know if it works or not :)

Comment: I put the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" on xml in the <EditText/> tag and nothing change. I put it on <RelativeLayout/> tag but nothing again. Finally, I insert this code "getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);" in the edit text in MainActivity class but didn't solve the problem and also it disables the function of the back button which is with one press (if the soft keyboard is off) you can move the application to the backround.

Comment: put android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" on xml parent layout instead of edit text......

Comment: or put this code in on create method.."getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS‌​_HIDDEN);"

Comment: I insert the command on XML but nothing <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" and I put this this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); and nothing again